# Unified struct in C to represent multiple sensor data

Tags: sensor, c, temperature, accelerometer, proximity-sensor

Working on desginging APIs for sensor events. I was wondering if there is a way to represent different type of sensor readings into a unified struct in C ?

For example a accelerometer'e reading represents 3-axial `data(x,yz)`, a temperature has `float` data type and a proximity sensor has reading in `integer`.
Is it possible to represent different sensor events into a same struct?

Found an example of the [Adafruit sensor library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor) which uses combination of `union` inside the sensor`_event_t struct`. Is it possible to define a struct without using the `union` technique?
Not that anything is wrong with it.

Is it possible to implement it with the `void pointer` concept?

Comment: regardless of how the interior of the struct is designed, there will need to be another field that indicates which kind of contents are currently in the rest of the struct

Comment: If you want portable C, go for `union`s. That is type-safe to some extend, in contrary to the `void*`, which additionally needs *another* object to point to.

Comment: As a matter of fact i do have sensor_type enum reference, but on using void pointer user might have to type cast the data every time a sensor event occurs. Is there any way to avoid casting  eveytime ?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a struct consisting of nothing but an enum to state the type, and a `void*` to the data. Then cast the data to the type corresponding to the enum before using it. That's how run-time type generic programming is traditionally done in C.

With standard C, you can also nowadays use the `_Generic` keyword to enable compile-time type evaluation, which is very handy when all types can be determined at compile-time.

More modern/advanced forms of type generic programming with an object-oriented design uses the concept of *opaque type*/*opaque pointers* which can be useful for writing hardware abstraction layers in embedded systems. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824329/partitioning-struct-into-private-and-public-sections). Though obviously in embedded systems you shouldn't use malloc, but some manner of [static allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440476/static-allocation-of-opaque-data-types).

The unions in the linked example only serve to enable different forms of notation, like either referring to 3 variables by x, y or z, or as an array. This is called *type punning* (through union) and is perfectly OK in C. In C++ it is an undefined behavior bug. Since the library is intended for Arduino C++, it is therefore without doubt completely broken. So when looking for inspiration of how to write proper programs, I'd strongly recommend avoiding hobbyist github projects, including everything labelled 'Arduino'.

Comment: +1 for the hobbyist's projects. :-) It is really hard to find at least *one* without serious problems.

Comment: @thebusybee Sadly, it is really hard to find well-written embedded C outside commercial software stacks. Open source libs from the well-known silicon vendor are if possible even worse than hobbyist projects. There's some sort of competition going on between them over who's got the worst programmers...

Comment: @Lundin - completely agree on the silicon vendor stacks; not only broken (a lot of lib functions just do not work) but opaque. I found a DMA setup function that was over 10 calls deep but which I was able to do with a single line of code using the CMSIS headers.(after declaring the necessary structure of  course).

Comment: @PeterSmith ...or a CRT that runs your entire .bss and .data initialization on a slow internal RC oscillator, while leaving the watchdog and LVD disabled...